# Scrapy xpath iterate (shell works)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to scrape some info from the companieshouse of the UK using scrapy.
I made a connection with the website through the shell and throught he command

```
 scrapy shell https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a
```

and with

```
response.xpath('//*[@id="results"]').extract()
```

I managed to get the results back.

I tried to put this into a program so i could export it to a csv or json. But I am having trouble getting it to work.. This is what i got;

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "gov2"

def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a']

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//*[@id="results"]').extract()
    print(products)
```

Very simple but tried a lot. Any insight would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These lines of code are the problem:

```
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a']
```

The [`start_requests`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) method should return an iterable of `Request`s; yours returns `None`.

The default `start_requests` creates this iterable from urls specified in `start_urls`, so simply defining that as a class variable (outside of any function) and not overriding `start_requests` will work as you want.

Comment: Thank you very much that worked for me! God bless your soul!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "gov2"
    start_urls = ["https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/search?q=a"]

    def parse(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//*[@id="results"]').extract()
        print(products)
```